# Python MapReduce - Count Frequency of numbers in a csv column

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

```
A B C D
1 x x 2
1 x x 4
1 x x 5
2 y z 2
3 d 3 8
5 u e 3
4 e r t
```

I have a csv file with the sample data above. I wrote a mapper that would produce key '[0-2]' if value reader[0] is between the values of 0 and 2. And, produce the frequency of the values of the first column reader[0]. By the time I run my reducer, I'd like to see:

```
(0-2] 3
(3-4] 2
(5-6] 1
```

Here's what I tried:

```
import sys
import re

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    reader = line.split(",")
    for l in reader:
        #pseudo if reader[0] is between (0-2]
        print('%s/t%s' % reader[0], 1)
```

Comment: please clarify if you are summarizing values from all columns or just column A.

Comment: @PeterK - Summarizing values from column A, just as the intended output shows 1 is between 0-2 and it occurs 3 times. Thanks.

Comment: Where's your reducer code?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about managing a `.csv` file there are easier ways [base python has csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), and [pandas has read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). But if you want to process a very long stream that you don't want to store, and you have arbitrary, but monotonically increasing, boundaries between bins, this code should work.

```
import sys
  
cuts = [3, 5, 7]
reader = [0]*len(cuts)
# input comes from STDIN (standard input)
def which_cut(val):
    return [i for i,x in enumerate(cuts) if int(val)<x][0]

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    try:
      val = int(line.split(",")[0]) # picks just column A
    except ValueError:
      continue
    reader[which_cut(val)] += 1

lc = 0
for i,c in enumerate(cuts):
    print(f'({lc}, {c-1}] {reader[i]}')
    lc = c
```

There's still work to do on this code, it will throw an index error if there are values in A that are larger than the largest cut, it doesn't handle floats correctly, and it doesn't handle numbers less than zero correctly. For all these reasons and for simplicity, in practice I would probably use [numpy.histogram()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).

Answer (score 0):

> By the time I run my reducer, I'd like to see:...

In order to get the output `(0-2]`, you're going to need to create that key in your mapper. Otherwise, you're going to get the total per number

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out. Do you mind seeing the real task at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65187820/python-mapreduce-count-frequency-of-numbers-in-a-file